# How to make transparent navbar when scroll to top of document

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I try to use my code for make transparent navbar(opacity = 0) when scroll to top document and set to opacity = 1 when scroll passing the object. But it's seem the code not working for me. Can someone look my code from jsFiddle and solve this problem?
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/phongphan117/66xjehgt/)

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    var o = $(document).scrollTop() / 500;
    if (o > 1.000) { o = 1;}
    var e = $('nav');
    var currentColor = $('nav').css('background-color');
    var lastComma = currentColor.lastIndexOf(')');
    var newColor = currentColor.slice(0, lastComma - 1) + ", "+ o + ")";
    $('nav').css('background-color', newColor);
});
```

Comment: I mean background color of navbar only. not navbar object. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

- `materialize.min.css` applies the `background-color` with an
  `!important` flag with it. And since [`!important` flag can override
  inline
  styles](https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/), you
  will need another `!important` flag to override that when applying
  inline styles. Messy I know but I cannot think of any other way.
- You are extracting `rgb` (without alpha) values from the element, but you want to apply `rgba` (with alpha) to it. Your resulting `newColor`
  variable will need to accommodate that.
- Finally, applying through `.css()` wouldn't help here. We will need to use `.attr()` to apply directly to the `style` attribute and concatenate all together in a string format.

Here is what you can do I think:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) { updateColor(); });

function updateColor() {
  var o = $(document).scrollTop() / 500;
    if (o > 1.000) { o = 1; }
    var e = $('nav');
    var currentColor = e.css('background-color');
    var rgb = currentColor.replace(/^(rgb|rgba)\(/, '').replace(/\)$/, '').replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
    var newColor = 'rgba(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ',' + o + ')';
    e.attr('style', 'background-color: ' + newColor + ' !important');
}

updateColor();
```

***Snippet:***

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) { updateColor(); });

function updateColor() {
  var o = $(document).scrollTop() / 500;
    if (o > 1.000) { o = 1; }
    var e = $('nav');
    var currentColor = e.css('background-color');
    var rgb = currentColor.replace(/^(rgb|rgba)\(/, '').replace(/\)$/, '').replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
    var newColor = 'rgba(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ',' + o + ')';
    e.attr('style', 'background-color: ' + newColor + ' !important');
}

updateColor();
```

```css
header, main, footer { padding-left: 0px; }
a.button-collapse { padding-left: 15px; }
a.brand-logo.left-align.hide-on-med-and-down { padding-left: 20px; }
a.brand-logo.left-align.hide-on-small-only.hide-on-large-only { font-size: 1.675rem; }
a.brand-logo.left-align.hide-on-small-only.hide-on-large-only span { font-size: 1.12rem; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  a.brand-logo.left-align.hide-on-med-and-up { font-size: 1.15rem; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  a.brand-logo.left-align.hide-on-med-and-up { font-size: 1.25rem; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://materializecss.com/js/init.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="navbar-fixed" id="top">
    <nav class="orange"> <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
      <a class="brand-logo left-align">Header</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light" id="test">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light">Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav left-align" id="mobile-demo">
        <li class="waves-effect waves-red" style="width: 100%;"><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect waves-red" style="width: 100%;"><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect waves-red" style="width: 100%;"><a>Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="waves-effect waves-red" style="width: 100%;"><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<main style="margin-top: -64px;">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; min-height:480px; background-color: #ccc; font-size: 3rem; vertical-align: center;">
    <div class="valign-wrapper center-align" style="margin-top: 65px;">
      <div class="valign">Transparent Navbar Section</div>
      <div class="valign grey-text text-darken-" 2 style="">(Opacity = 0%)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="navopc-endchange"><u>End Color Opacity Change!(Opacity = 100%)</u></p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</main>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank, It's work. Can you explain about `rgb` and `newColor` variables?

Comment: Sure. **1.** `currentColor` stores `background-color`. **2.** `rgb` values are extracted and stored in an array called `rgb` from this `currentColor`. **3.** `newColor` is formed by adding `rgb` array values as well as `o` variable appended to it form an `rgba`. Does that help?

Comment: Hey @phongphan117, did my suggestion work for you? did the answer help? let me know.

Comment: It's work on jsFiddle. And my code is work too, But in console of my code it's show "_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined_"

Comment: Not sure what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var o = $(document).scrollTop() / 500;
    if (o > 1.000) { o = 1;}
    var e = $('nav');
    $('nav').css('opacity', o);
});
```

You need to change the opacity attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle with some new code:
First I completely replaced your jquery with a more simple function that I wrote for one of my websites:

```
//nav snap
$(window).scroll(function(scroll) {
    var navStart = $('.navopc-endchange').offset().top;
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > navStart) {
        $('nav').addClass('opaque');
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('opaque');  
    }
});
```

It adds a class `opaque` to your navigation when you scroll past the top of the section beneath your top section (scrolling from the area where you want a transparent nav to where you want an opaque nav), and removes that class if you scroll back up.

I also added some new CSS:

```
nav {opacity:0;transition:opacity 0.3s;}
nav.opaque {opacity:1;}
```

This CSS just adds the properties for `opacity:0` & `opacity:1` for `nav` and `nav.opaque` and then I created a transition to make it fade nicely over 0.3 seconds.

http://jsfiddle.net/66xjehgt/5/

Comment: It's seem navbar was hidden. But I mean use my current color and adjust opacity from `rgba(r,g,b,a)`. Such as top: `a=0`; half of grey object `a=0.5` and end of grey object: `a=1`

Comment: Oh, that can be solved easily by changing `opacity:0` in the CSS styles I wrote to `background-color:rgba(255, 152, 0, 0)` and `opacity:1` to `background-color:rgba(255, 152, 0, 1)`. **THAT SAID** you actually have a different issue that's going to cause this to break. Your imported styles which give you the orange color on your `.orange` class has the CSS attribute `background-color:orange !important;`, so you need to remove that class and set the color on your nav manually or else the `!important` will take precedence over everything else.

Comment: You'll also need to update the transition to say `transition:background-color 0.3s`